# Can I style the results of a PHP query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Say I have this code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id";
```

Can I also include instructions in this sequence as to how to style the results of the the query (the 'array?). Could I say 'make the first result bold, and the rest of them regular font,' for example?

Comment: Do this in the PHP code that produces the HTML output from the query.

Comment: If you're outputting the results to an HTML table, you could do it in CSS. `tr:first-child { font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: but to answer the question as asked, No the sql query has nothing to do with the style, but this can be done easily with php when you build your results.

Comment: @happymacarts So do it (as Barmar said) in the CSS/HTML, yeah?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are connecting to your db but you could do something like this (untested)

**PHP**

```
// I typicaly load this part in a different file to protect my passwords 
$hostname = "127.0.0.1"; 
$database = "db_name"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = "Password"; 
$connStr = 'mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $database;
$conn = new PDO ( $connStr, $username, $password );
//////////////////////

$tbl_name = 'the_table';
$sql="SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$stmt->execute (); 
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

if($results){ // only execute this if there are results ?>
     <ul> 
     <?php
     $count = 0;
     foreach($results as $row){ //loop over all the results?>
        <li class="<?php // if this is the first row output the first-row class, 
                        // otherwise output other-row class
            echo $count==0 ? 'first-row' : 'other-row'; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['col1']; ?></li>
<?php $count++; // increment my count var
     } // endforeach?>
    </ul>

<?php 
} //end if?>
```

**CSS**

```
.first-row {
    color:red;
    font-weight:700;
} 
.other-row {
    color:black;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```